# controlling report filters of powerpivot using excel VBA

Tags: excel, powerpivot, vba

I had 10 power pivot tables which report filters needs to be controlled by a cell reference using excel VBA in Excel-2010

The same thing works for normal pivot table .

```
NewCat = Worksheets(6).Range("G12").Value


Set pt1 = Worksheets(5).PivotTables("PivotTable3")
Set Field1 = pt1.PivotFields("[Lead_f].[Lead_Generation_Month].
[Lead_Generation_Month]")

With pt1
Field1.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt1.RefreshTable
End With
```

Comment: And? What happens with a PowerPivot table? What is in the cell? You need to give a bit more detail I think.

Comment: cell contains the value which needs to be passed to the power pivot report fields.     The same code was woked fine for normal pivot tables ,but it is throwing run time error for power pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the main idea is having all 10 pivots in sync, the non VBA way to this would be to add a slicer to one of the pivot tables for filtering.  Then go to each of the other pivots and set the filter connection to your slicer.

Comment: @Marcus-Actually i need to pass that cell reference to report filters of pivot with different columns in the data .if all the columns are same then i can use slicer.but my requirement is different